# Individually available Hour Minute Seconds to HH:mm:ss format

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have an object which stores hour, minute, seconds individually.

```
public static class ETA {
        private int hours;  // 2 (single or double digit 24 hour format)
        private int minutes; // 0 (single or double digit)
        private int seconds;  // 0 (single or double digit)

// getters.. setters..
}
```

I need to save this time into a csv file with proper string as `"02:00:00"` with format of `HH:mm:ss`  and `NOT as "2:0:0"`;

I tried with StringBuilder append() method, but came up with very messed code. Here's what I tried...

```
ETA e = new ETA();
StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();
if (e.getHour() < 10) {
time.append("0" + e.getHour());
} else {
time.append(e.getHour());
}
// similarly for minute and seconds, and then returned time.
```

It doesn't seem nice to me. So How should I approach it in a better way?

Comment: Why don't you use some of the *already* in-built date features of java?

Comment: actually this DTO is directly mapped to the database. that's why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", e.getHours(), e.getMinutes(), e.getSeconds())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the pattern, you could convert your `ETA` to `LocalTime` first and use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

LocalTime t = LocalTime.of(5, 12, 42); //use your getters here
String s = formatter.format(t);
System.out.println(s);
```

This one also validates the date, i.e. it throws `java.time.DateTimeException` if one of the values is out of range.

Output:

```
05:12:42
```